# Join string elements from set literal in Clojure

Tags: string, clojure

Newish Clojure developer with a Python and C# background. I have something similar to:

```
(def coll #{
  :key1 ["string1"]
  :key2 ["string2"]})
```

I need to define a new string that concats the values of the two key vectors. I have tried

```
(clojure.string/join (get coll :key1 :key2))
(concat (get coll :key1 :key2))
```

And while these pull the string value of the first key, I can't get the second.

What is the idiomatic Clojure way to get and concat two values from a set? My desired output is:

```
"string1string2"
```

Comment: your collection is a set, not a map, drop the `#` symbol as currently coll has 4 items in it, not 2 map entries

Comment: Why are you using a set instead of a map? You could use `((juxt :key1 :key2) col)` to get both values in a sequence if you had a map.

Comment: Try `select-keys` -> `vals` -> `(apply str ...)` HTH

Comment: Thanks Mark and Lee. Switching to a map by dropping the sharp and then using (juxt) got the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a map, and I'm guessing you don't want the `[ ... ]` round the values, so that your collection should be:

```
(def coll {
  :key1 "string1"
  :key2 "string2"})
```

In that case, your first attempt wasn't far off:

```
(clojure.string/join (vals coll))
;"string1string2"
```

If you *do* need the vectors, because more data is going into each value

```
(def coll {
  :key1 ["string1" :more]
  :key2 ["string2" :stuff]})
```

... then you have to pick out the elements you want:

```
(->> coll
     vals
     (map first)
     clojure.string/join)
;"string1string2"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a map, rather than a set (as suggested in the comments) then

```
(def coll {
  :key1 ["string1"]
  :key2 ["string2"]}) ; {:key1 ["string1"], :key2 ["string2"]}


(->> coll
     vals ; (["string1"] ["string2"])
     (apply concat) ; ("string1" "string2")
     (apply str)) ; "string1string2"
```

Comment: This is a helpful illustration of the ->> macro. Thanks!